# Create an object that has a ForeignKey with another object

Tags: django, django-models

Assume that I have two models:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What I wanna accomplish is creating a `Product` object.

Assume I'll receive `category_id` from the `POST` request

```py
>>> category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)

>>> Product.objects.create(category=category, title='Send the category object')

>>> Product.objects.create(category_id=category_id, title='Send only category id')
```

As you can see, there are two options, the first is to send `category` instance to `create()` method and the second is to send `category_id`, so my question is which approach is better for **performance**?

I know that I need to check if that `category` exists in the `DB` or not but this is not the case that I'm talking about in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the primary key (`category_id`) there is *no* need to fetch the category first, you thus can use:

```
Product.objects.create(category_id=category_id, title='Send only category id')
```

which will thus only make one query: a query to create the `Product`, and thus will avoid querying for the category.

The two `.create(…)`s will make exactly the same query since Django will simply retrieve the `.id` of the `category` object, and make the query with that `id`.

> I know that I need to check if that category exists in the DB or not but this is not the case that I'm talking about in the question.

**No**, if one would make a request with a `category_id` for which there is no record for the table behind the `Category` model, it will raise an `IntegrityError`: the database will normally ensure that `ForeignKey`s always point to valid items, so the `Category.objects.get(id=category_id)` is *not* necessary: if you are only fetching it to fetch the category, you can omit that.

Comment: But if I use `DRF` I need to check if that `Category` exists or not, to handle the exception in case it does not exist, so in this case, it would be better to use `exists()` to check if that `category_id` exist or not instead of fetching the whole object, and send the `category_id` again to `Create()` method to create a new `product` instance if it's valid

Comment: @MohamedHamza: no, you can use a `try`-`except` to catch the `IntegrityError`. The Django serializers will indeed make checks, since if you use multiple `ForeignKey`s it is of course not clear for which one the `IntegrityError` is raised. But if you really want to get the most out of every query, you can thus drop the fetch of the category.